# How to Dock a bottom panel in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

### The Problem

I have a page that is a slider, simply displays an image, and you slide left or right to get to the next/previous.

What I am trying to do, is at the bottom of the screen overlay a panel where I can enter some text describing the image.

Here is my XML:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:ns="nativescript-carousel">



  <Page.actionBar>
    <ActionBar title="Customer On Boarding" icon="" class="action-bar">
    </ActionBar>
  </Page.actionBar>



  <StackLayout class="">
    <ns:Carousel height="100%" width="100%" pageChanged="myChangeEvent" pageTapped="mySelectedEvent" indicatorColor="#fff000" finite="true" bounce="false" showIndicator="true" verticalAlignment="top" android:indicatorAnimation="swap" color="white">
      <ns:CarouselItem class="slides slides-1" id="slide1" backgroundColor="#b3cde0" verticalAlignment="middle">
        <Label backgroundRepeat="no-repeat" text="Step 1" backgroundColor="#50000000" horizontalAlignment="center" />
        <!-- Dock Bottom -->
      </ns:CarouselItem>
      <ns:CarouselItem class="slides slides-2" id="slide2" backgroundColor="#6497b1" verticalAlignment="middle">
        <Label text="Slide 2" backgroundColor="#50000000" horizontalAlignment="center" />
      </ns:CarouselItem>
      <ns:CarouselItem class="slides slides-3" id="slide3" backgroundColor="#005b96" verticalAlignment="middle">
        <Label text="Slide 3" backgroundColor="#50000000" horizontalAlignment="center" />
      </ns:CarouselItem>
      <ns:CarouselItem class="slides slides-4" id="slide4" backgroundColor="#03396c" verticalAlignment="middle">
        <Label text="Slide 4" backgroundColor="#50000000" horizontalAlignment="center" />
      </ns:CarouselItem>
    </ns:Carousel>
  </StackLayout>


</Page>
```

and here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

At the bottom I would like a 100% width, roughly 100px high, bordered 'panel' I can add some text.

Does anyone have any ideas? I tried Dock Failed miserably. Ugh.

Thank You for looking.

John

Comment: `GridLayout` is the king. Use the text panel in row 1 and you can provide height there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GridLayout like the example below

```
<GridLayout columns="*" rows=auto, * " backgroundColor="lightgray ">
            <StackLayout class=" row=" 0">
  <ns:Carousel height="100%" width="100%" pageChanged="myChangeEvent" pageTapped="mySelectedEvent" indicatorColor="#fff000" finite="true" bounce="false" showIndicator="true" verticalAlignment="top" android:indicatorAnimation="swap" color="white">
    <ns:CarouselItem class="slides slides-1" id="slide1" backgroundColor="#b3cde0" verticalAlignment="middle">
      <Label backgroundRepeat="no-repeat" text="Step 1" backgroundColor="#50000000" horizontalAlignment="center" />
      <!-- Dock Bottom -->
    </ns:CarouselItem>
    <ns:CarouselItem class="slides slides-2" id="slide2" backgroundColor="#6497b1" verticalAlignment="middle">
      <Label text="Slide 2" backgroundColor="#50000000" horizontalAlignment="center" />
    </ns:CarouselItem>
    <ns:CarouselItem class="slides slides-3" id="slide3" backgroundColor="#005b96" verticalAlignment="middle">
      <Label text="Slide 3" backgroundColor="#50000000" horizontalAlignment="center" />
    </ns:CarouselItem>
    <ns:CarouselItem class="slides slides-4" id="slide4" backgroundColor="#03396c" verticalAlignment="middle">
      <Label text="Slide 4" backgroundColor="#50000000" horizontalAlignment="center" />
    </ns:CarouselItem>
  </ns:Carousel>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout row="1">
    // add text panel here
  </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```